# What causes ClassNotFoundException for an unreferenced class?

Tags: java, jar, classnotfoundexception

I've encounted an error trying to implement Apache commons-compress in my Java application:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry"

I have the exact same issue described in [this post](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/noclassdeffounderror-for-class-never-mentioned.71917/), except I'm not using Bukkit (whatever that is). The [expletive] OP left an infuriating last post, "Regardless, I found a solution. Case closed!" instead of sharing the solution, so I have no idea what (s)he did to resolve it.

I'm not using ArchiveEntry, but rather, TarArchiveEntry, which I assume imports ArchiveEntry. Even if I import the supposedly missing class, Eclipse warns of an unused import. Curiously, if I remove my TarArchiveEntry import, the warning disappears, but the line containing the reference to TarArchiveEntry errors.

I've never experienced this issue before. It would seem that the TarArchiveEntry class contains an error and fails to import ArchiveEntry, but I can't see a widely used library such as apache commons containing such an elementary error.

Is there anything wrong with my implimentation?

Comment: I've tried using other Java tar libraries, but I get the same behaviour. To reproduce, use the tar out example from here (http://code.google.com/p/jtar/) in a Java bean.

Comment: It would be a big help if you included a short example that demonstrates the problem. I compiled and ran the `TarOutputStream` example from the jtar page without any problems (it doesn't appear to depend on commons-compress). I also wrote a dummy class that imports `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry` (I had to search for the right package since you didn't mention it) and it compiled and ran without any problems. You must have a classpath problem somewhere, and a short example would help us determine that.

Comment: You might also try simple `javac` and `java` commands on a command line (with appropriate `-classpath` parameters) to isolate the problem from your Eclipse configuration.

Comment: I made this (http://pastebin.com/bvvj0EWM) class and created an instance of it in my backing bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed a problem with my classpath. In my project directory, I added the following line to the .classpath file (it's hidden, so look closely):

```
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/stockb/commons-compress-bin/commons-compress-1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar"/>
```

After adding this line, I no longer get ClassNotFoundException. I'm not sure why this fixed the problem, since I'm using several other libraries (e.g. commons-fileupload-1.2.jar) that aren't found in my .classpath file that don't throw any exceptions as a result.

My question now is, why didn't Eclipse modify this file when I added the jar to the buildpath within Eclipse? Also, why did I need to add commons-compress, but not commons-fileupload to my .classpath file?

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem with your CLASSPATH. You need to set it to contain the library that contains that class. It seems to be included in commons-compress, which means you should have a file somewhere named commons-compress.jar or similar, make sure it is in your classpath.

Comment: Is this AKA a "build path" in Eclipse? I have added the JAR to my build path of the project. I've successfully used several 3rd party JAR libraries in the past.

Comment: Also, there are no build errors in my project, which would be the case if my JAR wasn't being found. The error only shows itself at runtime when I go to load the page in my web browser.

Comment: Update- I've copied the jar to my WEB-INF/lib directory, and I get the same result. :-(